# MySQL ver. in Apache 2.4.18 on windows 10, does not meet Magento 2 basic requirments!

Tags: magento2, database

I have installed the latest Apache version 2.4.18. In order to install Magento 2. 
MySQL version is 5.2.12, but Magento 2 needs at least MySQL 5.6.
By the way, I found many solutions for Ubuntu, CentOS, but I want to run it on Windows 10.

Comment: Question, Are you using WAMP or XAMPP?

Comment: I've used XAMPP, but after installing wamp it solved. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how MySQL is installed you could just upgrade ([download here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)) or you could just use [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) which combines Apache, MySQL and PHP and enables you to quickly change versions